# Passing activated route params form parent component to children

Tags: angular, angular-activatedroute

In app-routing I have one parent component and 3 childrens:

```
{
   path: 'media', component: MediaComponent,
   children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'photos', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'photos', component: PhotosComponent },
      { path: 'documents', component: DocumentsComponent },
      { path: 'links', component: LinksComponent }
     ]
}
```

And in MediaComponent I get a route param like this: `this.activatedRoute.parent.snapshot.params.memberId;`

In any other components I tried the same thing and it is undefined. How can i get these params to childrenns?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you have access to this parameter in the MediaComponent, but you can try for the children the following:

```
{ path: 'photos', component: PhotosComponent, resolve { memberId: <value> } }
```

Then access it with:

```
this.route.snapshot.data.memberId.value
```

BR

***Update:***

```
@Injectable()
export class MemberIdResolver implements Resolve<number> {
  constructor(private yourService: yourService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): number {
    return this.yourService.getMemberId();
  }
}
```

Then in the app-routing.module.ts:

```
{ path: 'photos', component: PhotosComponent, resolve { memberId: MemberIdResolver } }
```

Then you can access is it in the component as I mentioned before:

```
this.route.snapshot.data.memberId.value
```

Comment: And how should I get my activated route in app-routing? Or what should value contain?

Comment: @AndreiKruza depends on what value you want to put there, I have made the following Resolver where I am calling a method from one of my services which returns an array of objects, but in your case it might be something like:

`ts
@Injectable()
export class MemberIdResolver implements Resolve<number> {
  constructor(private yourService: YourService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): number {
    return this.yourService.getMemberId();
  }
}
`